# Prevent mouse drag without interfering with input elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to prevent mouse drag for an app I am developing.

The following code works, but since I need input boxes to be clickable this still allows mouse dragging if the input box is focused. Is there a better way to code for this?

```
$(document).on('selectstart dragstart mousedown contextmenu', function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is('input') && (!$('input').is(":focus"))) {
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: In any case you don't need to use `preventDefault()` when `return false` is also added.